# A good resource for LAMP?

Tags: lamp

I want to learn about servers, not for any particular application, I simply want to learn. I am looking at LAMP, but I can't find any resources for learning about it. I have a giant book from 2004, would it still be applicable or should I use something more recent? I looked online but couldn't find anything beyond installation. Is there a comprehensive resource, preferably using Python (since I already know it) and preferably free, for learning LAMP? I don't know much about networking, is it a prerequisite for LAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.  It sounds like you would rather learn python instead of php?

Apache itself is very easy, you install it, and very rarely do you need to make any changes.  MySQL is mostly about learning the SQL syntax, Linux is a whole other domain alltogether, and you can use Apache, MySQL, PHP on Windows if you are more farmiliar with that.  PHP takes a while to learn but is best learnt (in my experience) from creating example programs.  Build yourself a blog step by step in PHP.

Knowledge of networking isn't too important.  You can install a lamp package such as XAMPP on your system, point your browser to 127.0.0.1 and you are done with networking.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: I already use Linux as my primary OS, and the reason I said Python is because I heard the P in LAMP can stand for either PHP, Perl, or Python. But yes, I would rather use Python. Thank you for the advice!